# What determines the rate of electron discharge machining (EDM) for different materials?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, metallurgy, machining, material-science

Wire EDM makes no contact with the work piece and disregards hardness.

I am using EDM to cut different materials, and I notice a clear distinction between the rate each material gets cut. For example, copper is extremely slow, while aluminum is much faster -- almost three times faster than copper. Lead also gets cut by EDM very easily.

My question is what determines the distinction in cutting speed for different material? Is it the melting point, or the energy of fusion, or something else?

Comment: Sounds like melting temperature from the materials you list. It's supposed to be boiling off or vapourizing the metal with sparks.

Comment: What characteristic changes at the rates you notice?

Comment: probably a difference in heat conductivity and maybe in electrical conductivity

Comment: Maybe specific heat or boiling point? Thermal conductivity shouldn't matter since the heat application is so fast.

Comment: This is an interesting question. If you can post the data from some different materials we can try to look for a relationship (if the answer is not already published and known by somebody).